# TinyS3 does not work. How to upload using REST APIS of AWS S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, boto

I want to upload/download files from S3 using the amazon's S3 REST APIs rather than the boto3 sdk. I came across the tinys3, which uploads based on apis, but it's giving me 403. I want to know is there any other python package which does the same ?

Also, for boto I came across a concept of session and aws_session_tokens. Can you pls. how to use that with the REST APIs since using boto3 and passing the aws_session_token, I am able to download file but without that it also gives 403? How to use this in REST APIS. ?

Boto code which works

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, aws_session_token=aws_session_token)
client.download_file(bucket, key, <filepath_for_download>)
```

However, when I try with tinys3, it's giving 403

```
import tinys3
conn= tinys3.Connection(access_key, secret_key, tls=True,endpoint= 's3.amazonaws.com')
with open('/home/test/test_upload.txt', 'rb') as f:
    conn.upload(key,f, bucket, headers={'x-amz-security-token': aws_session_token})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sessions for uploading/downloading to aws s3"?

Comment: If you get 403 it looks like you have a permission issue. Can I ask why you do not want to use boto3?

Comment: I read that tinys3 is now not maintained and hence it's throwing 403 ? I have a specific use case to use only REST APIs.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I have modified the question.Pls. take a look if you can help

Comment: A 403 error indicates 'access forbidden'. First, you can test your access by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) while using the same credentials. If that works, then the problem is either that tinys3 is using a different set of credentials, or is requesting access to a different object. I do recommend that you use `boto3` these days anyway.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your reply. I have a specific requirement to use REST APIS only. The same credentials work for boto3. I have added that in example. Can you pls. guide me on this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no knowledge of `tinys3`. If the credentials work for boto3, then it would appear that `tinys3` isn't signing the requests correctly. Given that the library hasn't been updated for 4+ years, it probably isn't using [Signature Version 4 signing process - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html), which is the signing method used on all modern regions. You'll probably need to write your own code instead of using `tinys3`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have successfuly used the AWS rest apis for s3 to upload a file using multipart. However, I am now stuck at the ```listparts``` call to AWS. If I call ```listparts``` api before and after the ```abort``` call, I do not see any difference(i.e. I can still see the same parts as before the abort call. Do you know why the ```listparts``` api not showing the correct response ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListParts.html

Comment: @Simplecode Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.